# spring data jpa cannot insert

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My entity

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "order")
    public class Order {

      @Id
      private String orderId;
      private Integer userId;
      private BigDecimal orderAmount;
      private BigDecimal despatchMoney;
      @Column(name = "`offer`")
      private BigDecimal offer;
      private Integer status;
      @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
      private java.sql.Timestamp createTime;    
    }
```

My repository

```
import com.lhrsite.shop.entity.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends BaseRepository<Order, String>         {
}

insert data 
Order(orderId=1534511221253786, userId=1, orderAmount=0, despatchMoney=0, offer=0, status=0, createTime=null)
```

Error msg:

```
2018-08-17 21:07:01.257 WARN 1227 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000 
2018-08-17 21:07:01.257 ERROR 1227 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order0_ where order0_.order_id='1534511221253786'' at line 1 
2018-08-17 21:07:01.263 INFO 1227 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
```

extract ResultSet

How do you solve the big cow?

Answer (score 1):

rename your table to something different than order (for example orders should work), order is reserved word.

Comment: yes, rename it to orders or just use this `@Table(name="`order`")" edit: I can't write it correctly here...[read more here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-escape-table-column-names/)